# "Bad Request" error when running example with --runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to Google Compute Engine, so this is probably a noob fail.

I'm trying to run the WordCount example from the [GitHub project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK).
The DirectPipelineRunner works fine, but when I try to use the BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner, I get a "Bad Request" error.
Note, I am authenticated via `gcloud auth login`.

Here's the [command line and subsequent error](http://pastebin.com/WSZJFab8).

I'm using Maven 3, Java 8, and Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Perhaps I'm not properly authenticated?
The error contains [this link](https://www.googleapis.com/dataflow/v1b3/projects/Theia/jobs).
This would be strange, since I can write to gs://theia using the local runner, and I can see a Dataflow tab in my Google Cloud project console.

Answer (score 2):

When I've had this issue it has always been some sort of authentication issue, including typo'ing my project name

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed indicative of permissions. Make sure the account you are using is a member of your project.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed an authentication issue, and had nothing to do with Dataflow itself.

For those interested, it appears my Google Cloud project was only partially created; I could create and write to storage buckets, but somehow I was never added as an owner.
Deleting and recreating the project resolved my issues.